# Drawing BufferedImage using ImageIO.write causing image to be resized

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I have this code:

```
public void draw(File image, int number, File destination) {

    BufferedImage img = null;

    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(image);
        //create graphic object
        Graphics2D graphicImg = img.createGraphics();

        //select the font
        Font font = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.BOLD, 96);
        graphicImg.setFont(font);

        //draw the text
        graphicImg.drawString(String.valueOf(number), 100, 100);

        //save on disk
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", destination);     

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error while trying to write on image!");
    }
}
```

I pass a File (which will be an image) as first parameter, an int and a File(which will represent the destination) of the file.

The method should draw a number on this file.

The problem is that the image size of the new image will be lower than original. For example, if I give a image with 3Mb as first parameter, the saved image will have around 1.5Mb. Why the size are so different and how I can fix it?

Thank you

Comment: Well what format is the original image?

Comment: You are talking about changing the actual size in BYTES, not resizing in terms of dimensions (width/height). Correct?

Comment: The image is resampled according to the created image settings. And I think that the default quality settings for JPG image writer is 75... and that is pretty low. You might want to check quality of the source image. Maybe someone will provide code for that :).

Comment: 1337: Usually it is jpg. Yes Pavel Horal, you are right. How can I save using the same quality settings of the original (File first argument) file?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGImageWriteParam.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html

Comment: Please go through the below link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21204627/how-to-prevent-loss-of-image-quality-while-using-imageio-write-method